# Is there a way to copy from the clipboard in android into terminal?

Tags: android, clipboard

I installed "Terminal IDE" on my phone.  However, I would like to copy certain URLs into a vim file.  This is what I am currently doing:

1. Open up default browser in Android
2. Copy a URL
3. Enter Terminal IDE or any terminal emulator on the phone and try to paste and nothing from Android pastes into the terminal

I have tried to paste in bash, paste in vim using `P`, and `"*p`, and I even tried to look for where the clipboard is stored.  I do not have a rooted phone so that last part was kind of difficult.

Is there a way to get stuff from the Android clipboard into Terminal IDE or any terminal emulator?

I have version 2.3.4

Comment: Could you show in more detail what you've tried so far.  It's not clear from what you've provided that this is even a programming question.

Comment: I guess there could be a programming solution.  Anyway, Mohammed's answer below led me down the path to a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Terminal Editor (Jack Palevich), in the Android market, allows you to paste content saved to your clipboard (on the actual device) into the command line.

In your case, after copying the URL from the browser, open up the terminal and long-press anywhere in the terminal until a box pops up with a list of options. The list should have a paste option, and it will paste the last thing added to your clipboard.

Also, you don't need root to use it for basic commands.

Comment: Now that they have ChromeOS, it would be nice to have a way to do it via keyboard (I'm on a Pixelbook). ChromeOS is a strange hybrid between traditional desktop and Android, I need to really think about being on Android when questions like this come up to be more successful with it!

Comment: Yeah, but how was it achieved by the programmer/developer? That's what I want to know. My first impulse was to use `xclip -i`/`xclip -o`, but of course Android doesn't have an `X` server. Maybe there's a similar utility for SurfaceFlinger.

Comment: @Khasm08 I found this question after Googling for a replacement to this very app, as it **doesn't** bring up this "long tap menu" of which you speak, at least not for me. Any idea why??

Answer (score 2):

friend as direct way .. I don't think its possible .. 
but here two ideas how you may implement your target:
First ONE: programmatically:

1-copy any address you'd like from browser and anything..

2-develop an application/service copies your copied text to logCat

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
                String copytext=clipboard.getText().toString();
                Log.v("URLS", copytext);
```

3-so link on logcat, filter it by URLS and get all your links .. 
4-may be you will need to trim text from other information you got in log cat, if you hate this, you can send results to file by:

```
adb logcat -s URLS > fileName
```

so you may find this file where you execute this command, lets say @ /home/user/, so file @ this folder .. if you need to go further, develop a program(in any language) to read this file and get the last line, and add it to your clipboard on your operation system.

so you have it ..

Second solution:with browser.
just sync your chrome browser with you gmail.. bookmark link and you have @ your desktop chrome browser :-)
and thats done.

good luck...

Comment: My adb or logcat are not working.  Do I need root permission for this?  Where do I place the ClipboardManager text?  Is that all the code I need in that file?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to fix the adb to able to use logcat.. no need for root here.  you copy the link you want or any other text... and launch the application which will send this copied text through logcat. or you can use chrome synch to get those links

Comment: It seems like this is a way to get the clipboard contents onto my PC.  I was looking for a way to get the clipboard contents onto a terminal on the phone.  Anyway, the syncing thing gave me an idea, and I also emailed the Terminal IDE developer and I am pasting into a text file on a notepad, and then opening that txt file in vim where yank/put can be used.  Not the prettiest way to do this, but sure beats remembering entire URLs.

Answer (score 0):

/data/local/nhsystem/kali-arm64/root/Downloads/

Here is ur root download folder create a txt file paste ur copied text and  type
cat <your_file>
Select text and paste in terminal